# In .NET MAUI, how can I set a name for a XAML-element, when the element is inside a collection or list view?

Tags: c#, maui

As an example, let's say a page has the following:

In XAML:

```xml
<Label Text="This is a text."
       IsVisible="true"
       x:Name="textLabel">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="LabelTapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

And then, in the code-behind:

```cs
private void LabelTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    textLabel.IsVisible = false;
}
```

When the label is clicked, it becomes not visible.
This is fairly simple and straight-forward.

**But how can I achieve the same effect, if the label was inside a collection view?**
In a list, I can't use the `x:Name` attribute, because it has to be unique.

Comment: You can't.  Items inside a template can't be referenced by name, because there may be 0, 100, or 1000 instances of that element at runtime.  You need to use data binding to set properties of the element from your model.

Comment: If you use the MVVM pattern, you can use a Model that contains observable properties like `IsVisible` and so and bind to them. Then update the `IsVisible` property and others based on your needs. Like Jason already wrote, you cannot use the `x:Name` attribute for templated controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I found a straight-forward way of doing what my intention was.

Say you have a stacklayout, with a frame inside, that is generated in a CollectionView.

```
private void CardTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    StackLayout stack = sender as StackLayout;
    Label myLabel = (Grid)stack.Children[0];

    if (myLabel.IsVisible)
    {
        stack.HeightRequest = 80;
        label.IsVisible = False;
    }
    else
    {
        stack.HeightRequest = 220;
        label.IsVisible = True;
    }
}
```

By using parent/child-relations, you can manipulate stuff inside a CollectionView, without setting a Name-tag, as one would if it was outside a list or CollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason and Julian has revealed the fact that you cannot access templated elements by its name. And the `Label`(named textLabel) is in `<DataTemplate>`.

In your first example, you have a `Label` on your `Page` and set its `x:Name:textLabel` in XAML,the XAML compiler creates a variable named textLabel that you can use to reference that control from your code behind.

However, if you have a [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/) or [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview) that has two Labels in it's `<DataTemplate>`, there may be 0, or 10, or 100 copies of that `Label` generated at runtime depending on the number of items in your `ItemsSource` which will fail to refer to the item by its name.
You cannot refer to it by its name because it is not a single and it is changing at runtime.

Alternatively, you can use CollectionView's or Listview‘s databinding to binding your properties in your `CollectionView` or `ListView` to your ViewModel. You can update your value of properties in `ViewModel` at runtime, then your label in `CollectionView` or `ListView` will be immediately changed.